# How to disable checboxes in loop before submiting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I got a loop of checkboxes. I put a hidden field inside with different value and different id:

```
<form>
<?php 
    for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
    {   
        echo "<div class='proc'> <pre>";
        echo "<h6 >Process: ".$proc[$y]."      "   ;
        echo "People required: ".$num[$y].".      ";    
        echo "<span class='assigned' name='assigned[]' >People Assigned: 0. </span>    <input id='unchecked' type='hidden' name='link[]' value='0'/><input id='checked' type='checkbox' name='link[]' value='1'><i title='Activate Process' class='fi-link'></i>Link Process</input></h6></pre>";
?>
<div class="procLeader">
<label>Leader:</label>  
    <ol>
        <li class="placeholder"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
    </ol>
</div>              
<?php       
    echo "</div>";                      
    }
?>  

<input type = "submit" style="margin-left:300px; width:150px;" id="savebutton" name ="submit" class="button" value = "Create Project" onclick="userSubmitted = true;"/>         
</fieldset>
</form>
```

What I want is to submit empty checkboxes also. and if user doesnt tick it set process column to 0 in database, and if ticks to 1. The problem is form sending both variables 1 and 0 if i tick the box. I tried to disable the one boxes which are ticked in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(document.getElementById("checked").checked) {
    document.getElementById('unchecked').disabled = true;
    }   
});
```

But I still got both values. Is there a way to disable hidden inputs if checkboxes are checked?

Comment: `id`s are to be unique. You have `$len` number of `id='unchecked'`/`id='checked'`. Since javascript expects only 1 `id='checked'` this -> `if(document.getElementById("checked").checked)` will only find the 1st instance.

Comment: @Sean so what is the way of achieving it?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question.. removed comment